# Can't convert WSDL into Apex Class

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, webservices, wsdl

I'm trying to convert an Apex from a WSDL file, but I'm struggling with it. Since I'm not an experienced developer, the solution may be very simple and I hope anyone can help me.

When I try to convert the file below to Apex, I get this error message:

[image]

I've tryed to use some internet tools and also convert the file to json and tryed to convert into apex.

The original file can be found in [WSDL File](http://webserver1.class.systems:8500/AgentService.svc?singlewsdl)

The original file has the *xs:attribute* problem that I fixed using the instructions on this [Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93891/unsupported-schema-element-found-http-www-w3-org-2001-xmlschemaattribute)

Thanks!!

Comment: Were you able to do it in any soap client like SoapUI?

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL includes the "AgentStatus" simpleType that isn't supported by `WebServiceCallout.invoke()`.

```
        <xs:simpleType name="AgentStatus">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="Prospective">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">100</EnumerationValue>
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
                <xs:enumeration value="Active">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">200</EnumerationValue>
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
                <xs:enumeration value="Suspended">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">300</EnumerationValue>
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
                <xs:enumeration value="Inactive">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">400</EnumerationValue>
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
```

It's used as the parameter to the "AgentStatus" operation via "tns:IAgentService_AgentStatus_InputMessage".

```
<wsdl:message name="IAgentService_AgentStatus_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AgentStatus"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

It's possible that this is getting mixed up with the complexType in the "urn:infospeed:classweb:api:contracts" namespace.

Are you able to update the WSDL (and the corresponding service) to make the types distinct?

In particular, in the schema for the "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Infospeed.Services.ClassWeb.API.Contracts" namespace you have both the "AgentStatus" simpleType **and** an element "AgentStatus" that is of type "AgentStatus" from the "urn:infospeed:classweb:api:contracts" namespace.